# Set variable as a function executes funtion after variable use

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm using express to handle some routes and views (`ejs` template).
Here is the route I use for my orders :

```
router.get('/orders/all', admin_check, (req, res) => {
  const orders = getOrders()
  console.log('----- orders got from function : ')
  console.log(orders)
  res.render(process.cwd() + '/src/views/admin/orders/all_orders', {
    orders: orders,
    test: 1
  })
})
```

As you can see, I'm passing in orders and test. orders has a value of `getOrders()`, this is the `getOrders()` function.

```
export const getOrders = () => {
  Order.find({}, (err, orders) => {
    let ordersMap = {}

    orders.forEach(order => {
      ordersMap[order._id] = order
    })

    console.log('returning orders from function:')
    console.log(ordersMap)

    return ordersMap
  })
}
```

So the problem here is that when this executes, it should pass the returned value from `getOrders()` into my `ejs` template, but instead it returns undefined.

So I added the `console.log()`'s as you can see, and there I understood what is happening.

The 2 `console.log()` in the router are executed before the `console.log()` in `getOrders()`. So it means that the variable `orders` is used before that the value is assigned.
To understand better, `orders` in `res.render()` has a value of `undefined`. This is because the function `getOrders()` only runs at the end of that `router`
I can do whatever manipulation I want, the `getOrders()` function will only be executed at the end of that `router.get()`

Comment: callback functions, promises, async/await are all things you may want to search to find an answer to your problem.

Comment: I've tried to transform it in an async function and do await `getOrders()` but that gives me the exact same issue.

Comment: Did you test passing "res" into your getOrders function and calling res.render within your Order.find callback?  Not sure if that's how you want to handle this, but that's one way to pass in a callback.

Comment: I've thought about that but the problem is that I'm using the function in multiple parts of my code and they don't all use `res.render()`, and just copy pasting that `getOrders()` function isn't the best way to fix it I think. JS is synchronous righ? So shouldn't it wait for that function to return something?

Comment: What library does `find()` belong to? Does it also have  promise version? Right now you have no return at all from the function. A return in a callback does not return to the outer function

Comment: `find()` comes from the `mongoose` package. It has promise support yes. But I don't really see how to use them, I'm pretty new to promises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So the issue here is that you are not waiting for `getOrders()` to return a response and proceeds ahead. This is the standard asynchronous way of things in Node.js
So to fix this, you can either call `getOrders()` with a callback and do your stuff inside that callback or use async/await and maintain the same structure of your functions like how it is now.

To fix it using the async/await, this is how you do it

```
router.get('/orders/all', async (req, res) => {
    const orders = await getOrders()
    console.log('----- orders got from function : ')
    console.log(orders)
    res.render(process.cwd() + '/src/views/admin/orders/all_orders', {
      orders: orders,
      test: 1
    })
});
```

and modify the getOrders function like this -

```
   export const getOrders = async () => {
      let orders = await Order.find({});
      let ordersMap = {}

      orders.forEach(order => {
        ordersMap[order._id] = order
      })
      console.log('returning orders from function:')
      console.log(ordersMap)

      return ordersMap;
  }
```

Comment: Huh? Where is there a promise being returned from `getOrders()`?

Comment: Yes I did but `getOrders()` returns an object and not a promise

Comment: @Trisma no it doesn't have any return at all in code shown in question

Comment: `return ordersMap` at the end

Comment: @Trisma that is inside a callback and does not return to the outer function. Using the promise version shown in this answer will help. Note you will also need to add error handling to it

Comment: Oh yeah I see, that's why. I'll try to implement that. Thanks